# Why return http 200 code from disk cache, neither expire nor cache-control in response header?

Tags: http, caching

The chrome browser return http 200 from disk cache. But I don't find "expire" or "cache-control" in response header? As I know, there should be expire or cahce-control in response, then the resource could be from cache.

`Access-Control-Allow-Credentials:true
Access-Control-Allow-Headers:DNT,X-CustomHeader,Keep-Alive,User-Agent,X-Requested-With,If-Modified-Since,Cache-Control,Content-Type
Access-Control-Allow-Methods:GET, POST, OPTIONS
Access-Control-Allow-Origin:*
Content-Encoding:gzip
Content-Security-Policy-Report:default-src 'self' 'unsafe-eval'; img-src *; child-src 'self' *; connect-src 'self' * wss:; script-src 'self' 'unsafe-eval' 'unsafe-inline' *.modules.yaas.io js.stripe.com *.sapjam.com *.hanatrial.ondemand.com; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' sapui5.hana.ondemand.com data: *.yaas.io api.eu.yaas.io api.us.yaas.io s3.amazonaws.com accounts.sap.com
Content-Type:application/x-javascript
Date:Fri, 14 Jul 2017 03:23:27 GMT
Etag:W/"59675378-8db28"
Last-Modified:Thu, 13 Jul 2017 11:03:20 GMT
Server:nginx/1.11.13
Vary:Accept-Encoding
X-Frame-Options:SAMEORIGIN
X-Vcap-Request-Id:34e06156-0a53-49d8-6e1e-f0ad50ac46bb
X-Xss-Protection:1; mode=block`

[Please see the http response header screen shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0wICJ.png)

When I use firefox firebug to do investigation. There is a cache section indicate a expire date, but there is no expire date in response header.

Comment: https://www.greenbytes.de/tech/webdav/rfc7234.html#heuristic.freshness

Comment: thanks for you information.

Answer (score 3):

If server do not provide explicit expiration times, a cache MAY assign a heuristic expiration time.

Defined in RFC 7234 [Section 4](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7234#section-4.2) and Section 4.2.2

One heuristic algorithm is

('date header value' - 'last-modified header value') * 10%